# Is there any Ready-to-use DynamicObject in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewbag, dynamicobject

I know **viewbag** is one of the ready-to-use DynamicObject, but if you are not in a view or controller, is there any other Ready-to-use **DynamicObject** except to write your own?

(btw, I found a sample of a great implement http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dynamicincsharp.aspx )

I am really lazy and just want to use some already made DynamicObject.

Comment: What do you want to do with your dynamic object? Cant you just use the dynamic type? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

Comment: I have to write extra code for me to use the dynamic object, I found answer below, which I can just use it directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [ExpandoObject Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

> **ExpandoObject Class**
>
> Represents an object whose members can be dynamically added and removed at run time.